# How to stop infinite loop in axios interceptors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, token

I would like to stop the infinite loop that I am getting with my axios interceptors.
When the user logs in, tokens are set in the local storage.
To test if token are being handled well, I change the value of the refresh token, and delete the access token, from the local storage.
When i do that, the user is suposed to be redirected to the login page, but it ends up in a infinite loop, unauthorized 401 error.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { logout } from "../stores/actions/authActions";
import store from "../stores";
import userEnv from "userEnv";
import { REFRESH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT } from "../constants/apiUrlConst";
import { ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY } from "../constants/tokenConst";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: userEnv.apiUrl,
});

const refreshAccessToken = async () => {
  const refresh_token = localStorage.getItem(REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY);
  if (!refresh_token) {
    store.dispatch(logout());
    localStorage.clear();
    window.location.href = "/";
  } else {
    try {
      const response = await axiosInstance.get(REFRESH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT);
      const access_token = response.data.access_token;
      const new_refresh_token = response.data.refresh_token;
      localStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, access_token);
      localStorage.setItem(REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY, new_refresh_token);
      return access_token;
    } catch (error) {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  }
};

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    const url = config.url.toLowerCase();
    const method = config.method.toLowerCase();

    const token =
      url === REFRESH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT && method === "get"
        ? localStorage.getItem(REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY)
        : localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY);
    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }

    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  async (error) => {
    // 401 Unauthorized
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    if (error.response?.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
      originalRequest._retry = true;
      try {
        await refreshAccessToken();
        return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
      } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default axiosInstance;
```

Could anyone help me find whats causing this loop, and how do i stop it?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to add a boolean flag to track if the refresh token has already been refreshed. this will prevent the interceptor from repeatedly retrying the request if it fails.

```
const alreadyRefreshed = originalRequest._alreadyRefreshed;
if (error.response?.status === 401 && !alreadyRefreshed) {
  originalRequest._alreadyRefreshed = true;
```

by checking for this flag, the interceptor will only attempt to refresh the token once, preventing the infinite loop.

Comment: thank you for taking the time. I tried the above on the response interceptor, but it didnt work. Same loop

Answer (score 1):

returning the axiosInstance call inside the try block and removing the return statement on the refreshToken() function.

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  async (error) => {
    // 401 Unauthorized
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    if (error.response?.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
      originalRequest._retry = true;
      try {
        await refreshAccessToken();
        return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
      } catch (error) {
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks mate. But i am still getting the same result. Could it be in the refresh token function? I read on the internet that i am not supose to use the same axios instance. Is that true?

Comment: @raio Yes, it is generally not recommended to use the same axios instance when trying to refresh tokens. This is because interceptors are global and attached to the axios instance, so it can cause unexpected behavior if used for multiple requests.

Comment: also trying by removing `originalRequest._retry = false;` 
`await refreshAccessToken();`

Comment: remove await refreshToken?

Comment: no, remove the  originalRequest._retry line and just return the axiosInstance call

Comment: Same result mate

Comment: @raio i updated the code, try with that, and if still same, then its something else

Comment: Must be something else. Thank you anyway tho